# How to add validation Rule for dynamically created multiple input in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, validation

Account Model Class:

```
 [Table("Accounts")]
    public class Account
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public float Interval { get; set; }
    }
```

Mobile Model Class:

```
public class Mobile
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public static Mobile Add(string mobile)
    {
        Mobile mobiles = new Mobile();
        mobiles.MobileNo = mobile;

        return mobiles;
    }
}
```

Thus an account can have multiple mobile numbers. Now I create a form where multiple mobile numbers can be inserted:

```
@model PowerSupply.Models.CompanyAccountViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Register</h3> <br />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Interval, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Interval, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Interval, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            <span class="add-new-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="add_mobile"> </span>
            <input name="Mobile" class="form-control" id="mobile_no" />

        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group row new_mobile_wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="new_mobile_container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-1" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

the form look likes:
[image]

And Finally I set validation as follows:

```
public CompanyAccountViewModel Handle(CompanyAccountRegistrationResponseMessage message, CompanyAccountViewModel viewModel, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{

    if(!message.ValidationResult.IsValid)
    {
        foreach(var error in message.ValidationResult.Errors)
        {
            switch (error.PropertyName)
            {
                case "CompanyName":
                    modelState.AddModelError("Name",error.ErrorMessage);
                    break;
                case "Interval":
                    modelState.AddModelError("Interval",error.ErrorMessage);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return viewModel;
}

 public class CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessageValidator : AbstractValidator<CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessage>
    {
        public CompanyAccountRegistrationRequestMessageValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x=>x.CompanyName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a Company Name");
            RuleFor(x=>x.Interval).ExclusiveBetween(0,10).WithMessage("Interval value must be between 1 and 9");
        }

    }
```

This two validation Rules works perfectly. I want to apply validation to *Mobile* too, ie: mobile number should be unique. How can I do this?

***Modification:***

```
public class CompanyAccountViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Interval { get; set; }
    public List<string> Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the method to add a mobile to the collection should belong to the Account class and not to the mobile class

Comment: Also post the View Model definition. Looks like the container ship model is improper, an Account should contain a property of List of Mobiles with each mobile entity itself imposing the required validation

Comment: Thanks for your time. I modified my question accordingly.